# Ошибка undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

```
#include "figure.h"
#include <cmath>

Figure::Figure(double r0): r(r0) {}

double Figure::volume() {

return 4.0/3.0*M_PI*pow(r, 3);
}

double Figure::square_area() {
return 4*M_PI*pow(r, 2);
}

void Figure::change_size(double x){
this -> r = r*x;
}
```

```
Build log: mingw32-g++.exe  -o C:\prog\BegC4D\task5.sem2\figure.exe C:\prog\BegC4D\task5.sem2\figure.o   
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это сообщение означает, что в коде программы не была определена главная функция для Windows-приложения по умолчанию - [WinMain()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Она является точкой входа в программу, если в настройках компиляции эта точка входа не переопределена.

Либо добавьте эту функцию, либо измените настройки компиляции, указав, с какой из имеющихся функций начинать выполнять код, либо измените тип подсистемы с GUI на Console.

Если Вы не хотите использовать `WinMain()`, но пишите под Windows с GUI, то линкуйте с опциями `/subsystem:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup` и определяйте стартовую функцию `void mainCRTStartup(void)`.